# R - Using a While() loop inside a FOR() loop

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

I am rebuilding a VBA code inside R, that counts transitions from a rating to another based on different conditions:

It is as follows:

```
## attach the relevant data table
attach(cohort)

# define the matrices that will contain all the counting information
ni = matrix(0,nrow = 1, ncol = classes - 1)
nij = matrix(0, nrow = classes-1, ncol = classes+1)

for (k in 1:obs)
{

  # define the year of the kth observation
  t = apply(data.frame(date[k],ystart),1,max, na.rm = F) 
  #t = year(as.Date(t))

  while (t < yend)
  {
    # if this observation and the second one belong to the same id and year, break and move to the next one
    if (id[k] == id[k+1] & date[k] == date[k+1]) {break}

    # if the rating of this observation is 0 (not rated) or in default, then leave it
    if (rating[k] == classes | rating[k] == 0) {break}

    # add to the group of customers with rating = rating_k, 1 observation 
    rating_k = rating[k]
    ni[rating_k] = ni[rating_k]+1

    # determine the rating from end of next year
    if (id[k] != id[k+1] | date[k+1] > (t+1)) 
      {newrat = rating_k}
    else
    {
      kn = k +1
      while (date[kn]==date[kn+1] & id[kn]==id[kn+1])
      {
        if (rating[kn]==classes) {break}
        Kn = kn+1
      }
      newrat = rating[kn]
    }

    nij[rating_k, newrat] = (nij[rating_k, newrat]  + 1)

    if(newrat!=rating[k]) {break}
    else
    {t = (t+1)}

  }
  print (k)
}
```

At the end of my code, if the condition " if(newrat!=rating[k]) " is met, i want my code to break and move to the next K. Else, if the condition is not met, i have t = t + 1, where the code will go back to the condition inside the while(t

I added in the end "print(k)" to understand at which "for k ..." step the code stops, and it always stops at k = 9 while k = 1 to 8 are printed. In total, i have 4000 observations but only 8 are considered, though the loop never stops and R keeps running.